# How is jQuery.Deferred implemented with an optional new keyword?

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/), an instance of `jQuery.Deferred` constructor function can be created using `$.Deferred()` or `new $.Deferred()`. The `new` keyword is optional.

How can I implement something similar in my constructor functions?

Comment: The `jQuery.Deferred` function just is a factory function, which `return`s an object. The `new` will just be "ignored", it does not use `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is not called as a constructor, the `this` won't be an instance of it. So, you can use this on your favor to detect the `new`-less call:

```
function MyObject(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  if(!(this instanceof MyObject)) {
    return new MyObject(arg1, arg2, arg3);
  }

  /* Normal constructor code... */
}
```